# Conditional random sampling: n samples must add to Y

Tags: r, random, normal-distribution

How do I sample n numbers X_1 through X_n (in one go?) such that their total is a given Y, and knowing that the unconditional distribution of X_i is (or would be) the normal distribution with parameters mu and sigma?

Just drawing n normally distributed numbers and scaling them to total Y doesn't seem right. If the absolute value of Y is very large, it would tend to produce n outliers (relative to the unconditional distribution) as opposed to - I don't know - 1 outlier. Also: if Y is zero, the result doesn't make sense.

Comment: You could sample, say, 2 numbers N(Y/2, sigma) and N(Y/2,sigma), because mean values should be Y/2. But distribution of the sum of the gaussians would be another gaussian. And then you build ratio of gaussian which turns out to be something like Cauchy distribution. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try but that should be doable with the [**condMVNorm** package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/condMVNorm/condMVNorm.pdf).

Let me explain for n=2. We start with two independent Gaussian random variables X1 and X2. Set Y=X1+X2. Then it is easy to get the variance-covariance matrix of (X1, Y). Then, with **condMVNorm** you can sample from the conditional distribution of X1 given Y=y. And of course you get X2 with X2=Y-X1.

This is generalizable to any integer n by setting Y=X1+...+Xn and by considering the random vector (X_1, ...., X_{n-1}, Y).

---

## EDIT

Here is the code for n=3.

```r
library(condMVNorm)

# X_i parameters
mu <- 1
sigma <- 2

# (X1, X2, X1+X2+X3) parameters
Mu <- c(mu, mu, 3 * mu)
Sigma <- rbind(
  c(sigma^2, 0,       sigma^2),
  c(0,       sigma^2, sigma^2),
  c(sigma^2, sigma^2, 3*sigma^2)
)

# (X1, X2) given Y=y (where Y = X1+X2+X3)
y <- 5

# number of simulations
nsims <- 10

# simulations of (X1, X2) given Y=y
rcmvnorm(
  nsims, Mu, Sigma, dependent.ind = c(1, 2), given.ind = 3, X.given = y
)
```

Comment: I've posted my own answer (which seems to work). Is that indeed the thing that you had in mind?

Comment: Do you reckon that gives different results from my code? (Thus far, my code seems to work ok, but I need to run some more tests.)

Comment: @Řídící Your code is wrong, since you don't use `given.ind` and `X.given`.

Comment: I am going to suggest that both codes are mathematically equivalent (and that there is no absolute necessity to use given.ind and X.given).

Comment: @Řídící Then you don't sample a *conditional* distribution.

Comment: I do. My Xs neatly sum to any Y. As do yours.

Comment: @Řídící That does not mean it is a conditional distribution. I am phd in probability theory and you're not the one who will teach me what is a conditional distribution. Your code is wrong but go ahead with it since you are sure of you.

Comment: You are of course more than welcome to comment on the answer at the stats site that led to my code. I am sure they would appreciate a PhD in probability theory commenting. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/609156/370545

Comment: @Řídící Your code is not very understandable. Explain what you do if you expect comments. See [here](https://datascience.oneoffcoder.com/multivariate-cond-gaussian.html) section 6.4. The **condMVNorm** package implements these formulas. You don't use this feature of the package since you don't use `given.ind` and `X.given`. And you should have said earlier that you followed the answer on stackoverflow (which is correct). You can use this way or you can avoid these calculations with **condMVNorm**.

Comment: Many thanks. I am learning here!

Comment: Of course, I tried working with condMVNorm in my answer because your answer pointed to that. I take it that since I am not using its important features, I might use a less sophisticated library in my code.

Comment: @Řídící You can use a package for unconditional multivariate normal distributions. But that will fail with your degenerate Sigma matrix. If you want to use the unconditional way, don't simulate the last component X_n, just simulate X_1, ..., X_{n-1} and take X_n = Y - (X_1 + ... X_{n-1}).

Answer (score 0):

Revised

With more than a little help (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/609156/370545 as well as user Stéphane Laurent), I take it that this also does the job:

```
my_y <- 10
my_sigma <- 5
my_n <- 12
my_mean <- c(rep(my_y/my_n, my_n-1))
my_bigSigma <- my_sigma^2 * (diag(my_n-1) - 
                               (matrix(1, my_n-1, my_n-1) / my_n))
my_Result <- rmvnorm(1, my_mean, my_bigSigma)
my_Result <- append(my_Result, my_y - sum(my_Result))
```

−−

The following crude test suggests that the resulting sd satisfies my requirements.

```
myout <- c(rep(0, 100000*12))

set.seed(123)

for (i in 1:100000){
  my_y <- rnorm(1, 10, 5*sqrt(12))
  my_sigma <- 5
  my_n <- 12
  my_mean <- c(rep(my_y/my_n, my_n-1))
  my_bigSigma <- my_sigma^2 * (diag(my_n-1) - 
                                 (matrix(1, my_n-1, my_n-1) / my_n))
  my_Result <- rmvnorm(1, my_mean, my_bigSigma)
  myout[((i-1)*12+1):(i*12)] <- append(my_Result, my_y - sum(my_Result))
}

mean(myout)*12
sd(myout)
```

Which gives

```
> mean(myout)*12
[1] 9.984285
> sd(myout)
[1] 4.999353
```

Comment: you recognize your marginal sigma won't be your desired sigma, right?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I think I know what you mean. But if I would set my_y to N(mu, 5*sqrt(12)), then on average I would hope to get a standard deviation of 5 for the X_i. The plan is to use this technique to generate monthly data points from annual data points, without losing i) the annual data points, and ii) the standard deviation.

Comment: Mmm... no, it doesn't look like it. Let me write what I see as an answer (there is no way to do some code in comments on Stackoverflow, so answer would do)

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I've done exactly what I wrote in my previous comment and it works out fine for the sd.

Comment: Could you post your rng seed?

Comment: There's something wrong: the matrix `my_bigSigma` is not invertible by its nature (try to invert it and you will see).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent You are right, it is not invertible. I take it (from a bit of browsing) that this happens when there is some linear combination of the Xs which has zero variance. In this case, that linear combination is X1+...+Xn. Which is the constant Y, as required.

Comment: Theoretically this is wrong (and I wrote an email to the package author to point out this issue, the matrix Sigma should be checked for positive-definiteness). In practice here, the sum is *almost* Y.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, interesting way to sample normals, but you have to check what you got back

you sampling code

```
library(condMVNorm)

my_y <- 10
my_sigma <- 5
my_n <- 12

my_mean <- c(rep(my_y/my_n, my_n))
my_bigSigma <- my_sigma^2 * (diag(my_n) - matrix(1, my_n, my_n) / my_n)

my_Result <- rcmvnorm(10000000, my_mean, my_bigSigma, c(1:my_n))
```

you have now matrix

```
dim(my_Result)

[1] 1000000      12
```

looks ok

```
apply(my_Result, 2, mean)
```

produced

```
[1] 0.8373670 0.8266844 0.8293054 0.8366576 0.8358933 0.8316721 0.8415673
[8] 0.8377708 0.8256674 0.8316660 0.8350799 0.8306687
```

which is ok as well, but

```
apply(my_Result, 2, sd)
```

will produce

```
[1] 4.785463 4.786450 4.785305 4.785815 4.781498 4.787159 4.790677 4.788603
[9] 4.788610 4.787577 4.783270 4.786239
```

and

```
library(moments)

apply(my_Result, 2, skewness)
```

will return something like

```
[1]  0.0003224842  0.0006144637 -0.0009435844 -0.0016183800  0.0006096481
[6] -0.0016528886 -0.0016519665  0.0020264454 -0.0026967559  0.0009690657
[11]  0.0020904441  0.0016340393
```

which again looks ok

```
apply(my_Result, 2, kurtosis)
```

will return

```
[1] 2.999561 2.999075 3.005832 3.003915 3.006498 3.008577 2.998123 3.000093
[9] 3.008372 3.000561 3.001040 3.000248
```

which is close to 3 which is good for gaussian

Comment: Thanks for this. I did a different test in my own answer. I think that together this looks pretty good.